Limit Switch Not Responding After Keyboard Interrupt on Raspberry Pi GPIO
I'm working with a limit switch on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian OS. While testing, I interrupted my script with the keyboard, and since then, the GPIO pin no longer responds to the limit switch.
I've tried GPIO pins 16, 20, and 21. They all worked initially and detected the limit switch correctly. However, after interrupting the script on each of these pins, the Pi no longer reads the limit switch input.
Here's my code:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

SWITCH_PIN = 16
DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS = 200

GPIO.setup(SWITCH_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

switch_state = GPIO.input(SWITCH_PIN)
prev_switch_state = switch_state

def button_callback(channel):
    global switch_state
    switch_state = GPIO.input(SWITCH_PIN)

GPIO.add_event_detect(SWITCH_PIN, GPIO.BOTH, callback=button_callback, bouncetime=DEBOUNCE_TIME_MS)

try:
    while True:
        if switch_state != prev_switch_state:
            if switch_state == GPIO.HIGH:
                print("The limit switch: TOUCHED -> UNTOUCHED")
            else:
                print("The limit switch: UNTOUCHED -> TOUCHED")
            
            prev_switch_state = switch_state

        if switch_state == GPIO.HIGH:
            print("The limit switch: UNTOUCHED")
        else:
            print("The limit switch: TOUCHED")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()



I've run sudo apt update.
Using the rpi-lgpio package after switching from the old GPIO package due to edge detection issues.
The limit switch is connected from a GND pin on the Pi to the NO part of an SPDT 250V 5A Standard Micro Switch with Lever (Jaycar), with the GPIO pin for data to COM.
The switch was working fine with this script for hours before the interrupt.
I've tested with two separate limit switches and a brand new Pi 4.

What am I missing here? How can I restore the GPIO pin's functionality after an interrupt?
Thanks in advance!

You have both duplicates if switch_state == GPIO.HIGH: Change this to if switch_state == GPIO.LOW: in line 29.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
